# How do I make a mutableArrayValue that I can access through a relationship?

Tags: arrays, core-data, swift3, relationship

I've added a to-many relationship called `listItems` between my entities `Person` and `ListItem` in my data model, and then successfully added objects to a given `Person` using

```
    let personSelectedListItems = person.mutableSetValue(forKey: "listItems")
    personSelectedListItems.addObjects(from: selectedListItems)
    print("personSelectedListItems after addObjects contains \(personSelectedListItems)")
```

Where `selectedListItems` is an array of objects of type `ListItem`. The print statement gives:

```
personSelectedListItems after addObjects contains Relationship 'listItems' on managed object (0x6080000d2050) <PersonMO: 0x6080000d2050> (entity: Person; id: 0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://1350DE85-4F65-462A-9C36-1EEE3D5298CD/Person/p1> ; data: {
    age = Ky;
    firstName = Uykyu;
    image = <89504e47 0d0a1a0a 0000000d 49484452 000002cc 00000333 08020000 003d00d3 35000000 01735247 4200aece 1ce90000 001c>;
    isVisited = 0;
    lastName = Kuyuy;
    listItems =     (
        "0xd000000005140000 <x-coredata://1350DE85-4F65-462A-9C36-1EEE3D5298CD/ListItem/p325>",
        "0xd000000005680000 <x-coredata://1350DE85-4F65-462A-9C36-1EEE3D5298CD/ListItem/p346>",
        "0xd0000000023c0000 <x-coredata://1350DE85-4F65-462A-9C36-1EEE3D5298CD/ListItem/p143>"
    );
    locationCity = Uyk;
    locationState = You;
    notes = "";
    phoneNumber = "";
    score = nil;
}) with objects {(
    <ListItemMO: 0x6000000b6c20> (entity: ListItem; id: 0xd000000005140000 <x-coredata://1350DE85-4F65-462A-9C36-1EEE3D5298CD/ListItem/p325> ; data: {
    category = Meta;
    isSelected = 1;
    listItem = "Similar values";
    listItemStatus = 1;
    listItemWeight = 1;
    people =     (
        "0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://1350DE85-4F65-462A-9C36-1EEE3D5298CD/Person/p1>"
    );
}),
    <ListItemMO: 0x6000000af900> (entity: ListItem; id: 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://1350DE85-4F65-462A-9C36-1EEE3D5298CD/ListItem/p2> ; data: {
    category = Appearance;
    isSelected = 1;
    listItem = Attractive;
    listItemStatus = 3;
    listItemWeight = 1;
    people =     (
        "0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://1350DE85-4F65-462A-9C36-1EEE3D5298CD/Person/p1>"
    );
}),
    <ListItemMO: 0x6000000b27e0> (entity: ListItem; id: 0xd0000000023c0000 <x-coredata://1350DE85-4F65-462A-9C36-1EEE3D5298CD/ListItem/p143> ; data: {
    category = Behavior;
    isSelected = 1;
    listItem = "Good grammar";
    listItemStatus = 1;
    listItemWeight = 1;
    people =     (
        "0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://1350DE85-4F65-462A-9C36-1EEE3D5298CD/Person/p1>"
    );
})
)}
```

This is good, because I want to have these objects created for each `Person`, but it's bad because it's an unordered set that I'm seemingly not able to access. I'd like for it to be a mutable array so I can access each object at an index, but when I do

```
    let personSelectedListItems = person.mutableArrayValue(forKey: "listItems")
    personSelectedListItems.addObjects(from: selectedListItems)
    print("personSelectedListItems after addObjects contains \(personSelectedListItems)")
```

I get this error message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSManagedObjects of entity 'Person' do not support -mutableArrayValueForKey: for the property 'listItems''
```

Which is puzzling, since I don't know why `mutableSetValueForKey:` was was supported but the array version wasn't. I'd really like to be able to access the objects through the relationship, ideally through dot notation. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Did you set the relationship as ordered in the model?

Comment: @Wain I did not have that set originally, thanks for the tip! I checked the 'ordered' box and changed the relationship to `mutableOrderedSetValue`, and when I do `(person.listItems?.object(at: 0))` it's giving me the correct object. What I'm stuck on is accessing that object's attributes - do you have any idea how I could go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both @Wain and @TomHarrington pointed me in the right direction on this, but here's what the answer to my question was (after some searching and tinkering):

First and foremost, I needed to mark the to-many relationship as 'ordered' in the Data Model Inspector of my data model file. The second thing was to change

```
let personSelectedListItems = person.mutableSetValue(forKey: "listItems")
personSelectedListItems.addObjects(from: selectedListItems)
print("personSelectedListItems after addObjects contains \(personSelectedListItems)")
```

to

```
let personSelectedListItems = person.mutableOrderedSetValue(forKey: "listItems")
personSelectedListItems.addObjects(from: selectedListItems)
print("personSelectedListItems after addObjects contains \(personSelectedListItems)")
```

so that `mutableOrderedSetValue` would reflect the ordered nature of the relationship. After that, I had a returned set that was in order. Hurray! But now how do I access and change those individual objects through the relationship? That brings me to the third thing - I had to downcast the set to my class (called `ListItemMO`). To grab the first object in the ordered set and then change a property through the relationship, it looks like this:

```
    if let listItemSet = personVar.listItems?.object(at: 0) as? ListItemMO {
        listItemSet.listItemStatus = 0
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Core Data to-many relationships are **always** represented by sets. Part of the support for this is that `NSManagedObject` implements `mutableSetValue(forKey:)`, which is one of the documented ways to access the relationship. Since to-many relationships are sets, `NSManagedObject` does not support `mutableArrayValue(forKey:)`, as that error message indicates.

If you want an ordered relationship, mark it as ordered in the data model editor, and then you can use `NSOrderedSet`. It's still not an array but it does have ordering.

Comment: thanks so much for the info! How does one go about accessing the objects in mutableSetValue through the relationship?

Comment: I have `(person.listItems?.object(at: 0))` correctly giving me the object I'm interested in, but I'm having trouble accessing its attributes, is what I meant by my above 'accessing the object' comment.